# woocommerce Customising checkout fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to customise the woocommerce checkout page. The below works fine:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_city'] = array(
     'label'     => __('Town / City:', 'woocommerce'),
     'required'  => true,
     'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
     'label_class' => array('infotown'),
     'clear'     => true,
     'placeholder' =>   _x('', 'placeholder')
     );
```

Where as the following does not:

```
 $fields['billing']['billing_state'] = array(
 'label'     => __('State:', 'woocommerce'),
 'required'  => true,
 'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
 'label_class' => array('infocounty'),
 'clear'     => true,
 'placeholder' =>   _x('', 'placeholder')
 );
```

There's no difference between the 2, apart from the label, and the label class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for adding "newField" on checkout page? becasue i can see "billing_city" and "billing_state" are already there

Comment: i am trying to customise the original fields, by adding a custom class to the labels. the top example works where as the bottom one doesnt.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to override the label in billing_state?

Answer (score 0):

try adding 
- woocommerce language support, which is for translators
- check the add_action function in which you are adding it too 
- spacing can be a problem in the wrong places also

to add language support, try so

```
$fields['billing']['billing_state'] = array(
 'label'     => __('State:', 'woocommerce'),
 'required'  => true,
 'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
 'label_class' => array('infocounty'),
 'clear'     => true,
 'placeholder' =>   _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce')
 );
```

where i added "woocommerce" next to placeholder. :)